# Accessing Microsoft Excel RTD Server from javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, rtd, real-time-data

Are there any javascript libraries for accessing MS Excel RTD server? I would like to retrieve realtime data from a RTD server from javascript and display it in browser. I don't want to do it on the server side because it can become a scalability issue for my web server. (I do not want to use any activeX controls as I want to make it available for IE, Chrome and FireFox.)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any that I know of.  However, you can use django (or flask, etc.) and a simple python [RTD client](https://code.google.com/p/pyrtd/) to gather the information from your RTD server.  Then, you can have your browser-based client ask that (local) web server for the same information.